# why i code the node -v in cmd is success，but code the npm -v in cmd is error

Tags: node.js, npm

**i install node with msi，but is error when i use the 'npm'.**

**i spent a lot of time which searching for information，but still can't solve the problem，so i use the 'ask question' to ask for help**

> system : windows 10

> node version : 14.16.0

> System Variables : D:\Ide\NodeJs\ （my node installed path）

> User Variables : C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm （is empty folder）

```
C:\Users\Administrator>node -v
v14.16.0

C:\Users\Administrator>npm -v
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe
npm ERR! path D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-05T11_33_45_180Z-debug.log
6.14.11
```

i dont know what is wrong with it..

**in log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Ide\\NodeJs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Ide\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'prefix',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose stack Error: spawn D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe ENOENT
4 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
4 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
4 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Administrator
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
7 verbose argv "D:\\Ide\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\Ide\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "prefix" "-g"
8 verbose node v14.16.0
9 verbose npm  v6.14.11
10 error code ENOENT
11 error syscall spawn D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe
12 error path D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe
13 error errno -4058
14 error enoent spawn D:\Ide\NodeJs\node.exe ENOENT
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

i try to fixed it...

e.g.

1. reduce the 'node' level
2. reconfig the system path

help me .. please !!